# Does the number of scripts included in a site "significantly" decrease performance?

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, client-side

**Case 1**: 
On the homepage:

```
script(src="angular.js")
script(src="ember.js")
script(src="react.js")
script(src="knockout.js")
script(src="backbone.js")
...
script(src="jQuery.js")
script(src="my-project.js")
```

**Case 2:**

```
script(src="jQuery.js")
script(src="my-project.js")
```

---

In both cases, my-project.js only uses jQuery functions.

Initial load time aside, will jQuery functions take longer to execute considering that their are more scripts to look through?

If they do, is this time more than a couple ms?

Comment: There are a lot of smart members on SO and _maybe_ someone will know the answer to this question off-hand but the only way to be sure is to benchmark this yourself. For what it's worth, the impact is almost certainly going to be miniscule relative to the rest of the application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The more HTTP requests your page makes before it is functional, in general, the slower the perceived load time. That's why the first recommendation in the [YUI Best Practices for Speeding Up Your Web Site](https://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html) is "minimize HTTP requests." There's a *lot* of nuance there, but in general use script and CSS combining tools to group your script and styling into a single file each.

> Initial load time aside, will jQuery functions take longer to execute considering that their are more scripts to look through?

No, not at all. Once the scripts have run and the functions have been created, there's no difference whatsoever in the cost of calling them.